# How to change bars colour in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am new to programming so I am learning introductory to MATLAB I was wondering how you could change colours of bar in MATLAB.

this is my script. Can someone please help!!

```
x =[1:8]
for y = [20 30 40 50 60 70 80]
bar(x,y)
if y < 40
col = 'b';
else if y > 40
col= 'g';
end
end
end
```

i also tried bar(x,y, r) but it doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

Whilst this is overkill for your specific question, in general, to change the colour of bars depending on their height, you can apply a `colormap` to the bars. This is mainly from the [`bar` documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html).

```
x = 1:8;
y = 10*x;
h=bar(y);  %// create a sample bar graph
```

For the colormap `MAP`, you do this:

```
colormap(MAP)
ch = get(h,'Children');
fvd = get(ch,'Faces');
fvcd = get(ch,'FaceVertexCData');
[zs, izs] = sort(y);
for i = 1:length(x)
    row = izs(i);
    fvcd(fvd(row,:)) = i;
end
set(ch,'FaceVertexCData',fvcd)
hold off
```

And, for example, using the builtin `colormap` `hsv`, you get
[image]

But in this case we want a very specific colormap,

```
b=40 %// the cut-off for changing the colour
MAP=zeros(length(x),3); %// intialise colormap matrix
MAP(y<b,:)=repmat([0 0 1],sum(y<b),1); %// [0 0 1] is blue, when y<40
MAP(y>=b,:)=repmat([0 1 0],sum(y>=b),1); %// [0 1 0] is green, for y>=40
colormap(MAP)
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To use two different colors depending on `y`: compute a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) depending on `y` values and call `bar` twice with appropriate arguments:

```
x = [1:8];
y = [20 30 40 50 60 70 80];
ind = y < 40; %// logical index
bar(x(ind), y(ind), 'facecolor', 'b', 'edgecolor', 'k') %// blue bars, black edge
hold on %// keep plot
bar(x(~ind), y(~ind), 'facecolor', 'g', 'edgecolor', 'k') %// green bars, black edge
set(gca,'xtick',x)
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

[bar](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) can take third argument, which is color value, e.g. `bar(x,y, 'r')`.