# Matlab: Set bar chart colours

Tags: matlab, charts

I have a set of values and a bunch of corresponding colours. The colours are dependent on the x labels but they are already in the correct order. How do I plot the bar chart such that the colours correspond to the correct bars. For example...

```
y= [2 4 12 7 15]'
bar_colour={'b';'b';'g';'r';'k'}

hp=bar(y,bar_colour{:})
```

At the moment, all the bars are in one colour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change bars colour in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180337/how-to-change-bars-colour-in-matlab)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In the linked question, colors should depend on bar _height_. Here they should depend on bar _horizontal position_

Comment: @LuisMendo I read too quickly, you're absolutely correct. Sorry OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think a loop is justified:

```
y = [2 4 12 7 15]'; %'
bar_colour = {'b';'b';'g';'r';'k'};
hold on
for n = 1:numel(y)
    bar(n, y(n),bar_colour{n});
end
```

[image]